# Textbox gets validated by two buttons

Tags: c#, css, asp.net

I am making some web app using ASP.net and for look of the site I am using Bootstrap. But I have this problem that I can't solve by googling

So this is the deal .. I have panel and inside I have simple textbox and button

```
<asp:Panel runat="server" ID="pnlCompany">
    <div style="display: inline-flex; overflow: hidden; float: left">
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtClient" runat="server" CssClass="text-primary" 
         Wrap="true" Width="300px" required=""></asp:TextBox>

        <asp:Button ID="btnInsertClient" runat="server" OnClick="btnInsertClient_Click" 
         CssClass="btn btn-primary" data-target="#MainContent_pnlCompany_txtClient" 
        Text="Dodaj klijenta" />
    </div>
</asp:Panel>
```

But my problem show up here ... Under that panel I have another panel, with Button (that works fine, it collapsing table at end of page), then I have FileUpload button and Button (btnUploadUsers) that is giving me hard time, idea of this button is to go with upload of file, but once i click it, it keeps validating textbox (txtClient) from above panel ... I am sure this button fire it's event "btn_UploadUsers_click" because once i enter data in textbox, program stop on my break point

```
<asp:Panel runat="server" ID="pnlImportUsers">
    <div style="display: inline-flex; overflow: hidden; float: left">
        <asp:Button ID="btnCompanyList" runat="server" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" 
         data-target="#MainContent_pnlCompanyList" Text="Lista klijenata" />

        <asp:FileUpload ID="fuUsersUpload" runat="server" Enabled="false" 
        CssClass="btn-group-vertical" />

        <asp:Button ID="btnUploadUsers" runat="server" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" 
         Text="Upload" OnClick="btnUploadUsers_Click" data-target="#MainContent_UsersId" 
         ValidationGroup="fuUsersUpload" />
    </div>
</asp:Panel>
```

Let me know if I can do anything to describe this problem better, thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you @Benni_mac_b for advice, but i figured out what was a problem, so I'll post answer in case anyone else be in this situation.

So with using Bootstrap css and js, as you can see 'required' on the form, it will always be check if has value on every post_back

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtClient" runat="server" CssClass="text-primary" 
     Wrap="true" Width="300px" required=""></asp:TextBox>
```

So, as I didn't wanted my btnUploadUsers to do PostBack, simply adding

```
UseSubmitBehavior="false"
```

In my code snippet fixed my problem